# Shrink array to save memory

Tags: c++, memory-usage, array

In my project I need three arrays to store data inside.

I define a maximal number of elements as a macro variable. However, at a certain point in the setup function, the program could determine, that the arrays would actually store a smaller number of elements. In other words, it is possible (and even likely) that there is more memory reserved for the arrays than actually necessary.

As I think that memory might be a critical factor on a micro controller like the Arduino, I would like to set the excess memory free.

Is there a way to dynamically resize **and shrink** the arrays at runtime?

Something like this (pseudocode)

```
#define maxSize 50
int theArray[maxSize];

int actualSize = getActualArraySize();
// sets actualSize to a value <= 50, let's assume actualSize = 20
shrinkArray(theArray, actualSize);
// shrinkArray doesn't exist :) I need something like that.
```

Comment: Arrays can not be resized, but if you know the required size of the array *before* any data is written into it, you can declare `theArray` as a pointer instead of array: `int *theArray;` and then later allocate the required amount of memory: `theArray = malloc(requredArrayLength * sizeof(int));` - Would that solve your problem?

Comment: However, if it is not the case that you somewhere else use an inversely proportional amount of memory to the size of these arrays, it might not be necessary to save bytes here. E.g. if you conditionally reduce an array of ints from 50 to 30 elements, you will save 40 bytes of memory only if the condition is met and you can not rely on this memory always being available for other purposes.

Comment: thank you jarnbjo! `malloc()` could be a way to go. Actually it would be three arrays reduced from 50 to 30 elements. So 40 bytes * 3 = 120 bytes. I don't know enough about memory allocation on a micro controller but I thought it might be significant? If you could share your opinion and some more information about the "malloc solution" this would help me a lot!

Comment: ... to clarify: in my project I need to match a user input against a password. The input is stored (and translated) in the arrays. The password is stored in the eeprom and can only be changed in the setup function. But at compile time I don't know the exact length of the password. However, it is very likely that the password is much shorter than the maximal possible length.

Comment: I am not sure if you understood what I wrote in my second comment. What are you intending to use the 120 bytes for, which you *may* save, as long as you won't be sure if the memory is actually available. Do you have any other parts of your code, which will need more memory if a short password is configured? If not, spare yourself the effort and forget about those 120 bytes, since you won't have any situation, in which you can use them.

Comment: In fact I really didn't (and maybe still don't) understand what you wrote in this comment. If I get it right, you state that if there is *the possibility* that the arrays reach the length of `maxSize`, I might just as well allocate the memory fitting to `maxSize`. My idea is that the mc might run faster if it has more memory available - therefore the arrays shouldn't use more memory than necessary. However, my view might come from my lack of knowledge about the function of an mc. On a desktop computer, saving RAM would be advantageous, but is this also true for an mc?

Comment: and to answer your question: no, if the password is short there are no other parts of the code that need more memory.

Comment: The amount of memory available has no bearing on the speed the MCU runs at all. You are thinking of a phenomenon on PCs where when there is not enough memory available some memory is "swapped" to hard disk, which slows it down. Since there is no hard disk, no swapping, no memory management, none of that applies. So speed can never be affected by lack of RAM in the way you are supposing.

Comment: Neither a microcontroller, nor a desktop computer will magically run faster if you use less RAM. On a desktop computer, your software is usually running in a multitasking environment and it might be advantageous to save RAM to leave resources for other processes, but on the microcontroller you are 'on your own' and can manage the resources as *you* need them and not worry about other processes.

Comment: I see. In this case the only restriction is that all variables I define will fit inside the SRAM - no need to reduce memory usage as long as this condition holds... Thank you. Would anybody want to formulate an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Do the elements of the array really need to be ints? If the values you store in it are between 0 and 255, you could use a array of bytes, halving the amount of RAM required.

Comment: You could also consider hashing the password into a much smaller value, if memory consumption is a problem.

Comment: As a matter of fact, not all arrays are ints - this was just for illustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common question when designing software. The simple answer (rule of thumb) is **statically allocate the maximum size of the array**. In this case the maximum size of the arrays. This simple rule will keep you out of trouble and make testing etc much simpler.

Using dynamic allocation (adjusting array size etc) especially for small scale embedded systems such as the Arduino opens a "can of worms" with possible memory (heap) fragmentation and hidden concurrency and performance issues.

If the required maximum size of the array is 32 elements the application has to allow that and there is no memory to save. Statically allocating will make the sketch simpler and easier to test.

Cheers!

Comment: To elaborate a little, while you CAN allocate the arrays smaller, there's really no point leaving some memory free: the program has to work even in the worst case, with the arrays as big as they'll ever be, and it won't work any better if you sometimes have some memory left over.